# How to allow WiFi printer to work through Windows 7 Firewall?

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing, firewall, windows-firewall

If the Win7 Advanced Firewall is set to block unknown incoming and outgoing connections, how should it be configured to allow printing on a local WiFi printer?

During testing, I tried allowing all access to the IP of the printer, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling the firewall entirely and then try testing.

You will then establish if it is firewall related.

Try disabling your antivirus aswell.

Try using wireshark to see what ports is it trying communicate through, then open those ports on your firewall.

KR